# FloatingActionButton with Snackbar and transparent navigation bar

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout, android-snackbar

i have `<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>` in my `styles.xml`.

I give the floating action button margin because of the transparent navigationbar.

I have a problem that my snackbar is below the transparent navigation bar. I fixed this by given the snackbar a padding, but now between my snackbar and my floating action button is to much space. I tried to create a custom behavior for my floating action button, but the custom margin for the navigationbar and the padding from the snackbar caused wrong heights when the snackbar is dismissed or shown.

Thats my floating action button inside the `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` that has the attribute `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/myFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="12dp"
        app:layout_behavior="...ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
        app:rippleColor="@color/md_indigo_700" />
```

I haven´t found a solution for aligning the `FloatingActionButton` and the `SnackBar` above the `NavigationBar` without destroying the `behavior`.

My CoordinatorLayout is inside a fragment. And here is the activity layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
```

fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/fragment_toolbar" />

    <com.pnikosis.materialishprogress.ProgressWheel
        android:id="@+id/progress_wheel"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        wheel:matProg_barColor="#5588FF"
        wheel:matProg_progressIndeterminate="true" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/navigation_bar_bottom_padding"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/myFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="12dp"
        app:layout_behavior="...ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
        app:rippleColor="@color/md_indigo_700" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of using padding and all, try this, use an empty layout right above floatingActionButton, and in snackbar for the layout to show, specify this empty layout.

Comment: @HourGlass snackbar is always searching for the next coordinatorlayout in layout. A emptyview would make no different.

Comment: okay, can u share the whole layout code.

Comment: @HourGlass i updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do. Check it out, and if it's not working share your snackbar code as well.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/myFAB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="12dp"
    app:layout_behavior="...ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
    app:rippleColor="@color/md_indigo_700" />
```